# Какую переменную выбрать и как ввести текст?

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс домашнее задание. Я хочу туда добавить переменную типа string. Где человек может ввести до 5 строк , что то вроде выполнения домашнего задания. Теперь несколько вопросов:

1. Какую переменную выбрать лучше. Массив из string или что то другое.
2. Затем у меня идет запись в файл. Но эти данные нужно еще потом прочитать потом. Как их прочитать и вывести, если введено меньше строк.

Comment: я же вам помог?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Homework
{
private:
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    string task[5];
    int num;

public:
    void set_task()
    {

        out.open("file.txt");
        cout << "Количество строк: ";

        cin >> num;
        getline(cin, task[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        {
            cout << "#" << i + 1 << " - ";
            getline(cin, task[i]);
            out << task[i] << endl;
        }
    }

        void show_task()
        {
            in.open("file.txt");
            string myText;
            while (getline(in, myText)) 
            {
                cout << myText << endl;
            }
        }
    


};

int main()
{   

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    Homework h;
    h.set_task();
    h.show_task();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```